# Why does binascii.a2b_hex() return a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the description of the function from the [standard library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex).

> binascii.a2b_hex(hexstr)
>
> Return the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string hexstr. This function is the inverse of b2a_hex(). hexstr must contain an even number of hexadecimal digits (which can be upper or lower case), otherwise a TypeError is raised.

However, the following code sample prints out `Hello World!`

```
import binascii
print binascii.a2b_hex('48656c6c6f20576f726c6421')
```

Why does `print` interpret the binary data as a string? What exactly is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because in Python 2, all binary data is represented as strings. The `str` type is basically just a sequence of bytes.

In Python 3, the basic `str` type is a unicode value (`unicode()` in Python 2) and the Python 2 `str` type has been renamed to `bytes` instead, and the `a2b_hex` function outputs bytes:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.a2b_hex('48656c6c6f20576f726c6421')
b'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Martjin's answer is simple and complete, however those who found this ticket for some capability reference, please:

```
# equivalent of `binascii.a2b_hex` in python 3:
binascii.a2b_hex('48656c6c6f20576f726c6421').decode('latin-1')

# equivalent of `binascii.b2a_hex` in python 3:
binascii.b2a_hex('Hello World!'.encode('latin-1')).decode().upper()
```